# Global vs local for commonjs memory titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

I have a code repeated for every page in Titanium studio, so should i declare it in each individual page or in a global scope?

Something like this.

```
//app.js
test = require('test');

//page1.js
test= new test();
view.add(test.view);

exports.view = view;

//page2.js
test = new test();
view.add(test.view);
exports.view = view;
```

or should i do it like this

```
//app.js


//page1.js
var test = require('test');
view.add(test.view);
exports.view = view;

//page2.js
var test = require('test');
view.add(test.view);
exports.view = view;
```

my test.js is something like this

```
//test.js

function textField(){

     this.view = Ti.UI.createView();
     this.view.add(this.textField = Ti.UI.createTextField());
 }

 module.exports = textField;
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid populating the global scope at all times. As you are writing in a commonJS pattern make sure you are modular and always protect the global scope.

I always use App.js to reference a controller file eg.

```
var controller = require('/controller');
controller.loadApp();
```

Which then makes it very hard to populate the global scope.

Follow the second example you provided as the first time a module or file is required by using

```
require('foo')
```

it's placed into the applications memory, if another page or tab then calls the same require needing access to it it doesn't reload it, it just changed the pointer to that file, giving access to all of it's functions E.g your textField function.

Comment: I did it this way and it shows a significant reduce in skipped frames.thanks